# How do I install Google Chrome on a Kindle Fire?

Tags: amazon-kindle

I'm tryhing to install any version of Google Chrome on Kindle Fire using instructions here -- https://www.technipages.com/kindle-fire-how-to-install-google-chrome-via-apk-file.  I have followed all the instructions up to the point where I actually have to download an APK file, evidently needed to install Chrome.  However, I'm confused about which file I need.  On Chrome's site, all the files they list are for Android operating systems ...

```
https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/
```

In as far as I'm using a Kindle Fire, I don't see any APK files on the site appropriate to a Kindle.  Where do I find such a file?

Comment: Why do those questions belong on an Android site?  I'm not trying to install Chrome on Android, I want to install it on Kindle.

Comment: First, questions about installing Google Chrome are completely off-topic for [webapps.se]. Second, the Kindle Fire is based on Android, so is also off-topic at [su]. Android Enthusiasts is the best possible match. If this question doesn't belong here, then it doesn't have a home any where on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions on that site **pretty much explains everything**. Since *Kindle Fire OS* is based on *Android OS*, you just need to know to which Android version does your Fire OS corresponds.

Also check the appropriate CPU architecture. For example for *Chrome Browser 62.0.3202.84*, **click on all variants** (or [this link](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/chrome-62-0-3202-84-release/)), then on the next screen you see that for each variant there is a compatibility table for each CPU architecture (*i.e arm, arm64*) as well as Android version.

If your Fire is based on *Android 5.0* and *arm architecture* then, select that one for download and install.

Remember to reboot your device after installing